# Getting an nth element of a nested map

Tags: function, clojure

I would like to get the nth element of the nested map, but could not find the appropriate command and had got an error. I would need something that worked like a `first` function:

```
boot.user=>   (def db2 @main/database)
#'boot.user/db2
boot.user=> (def ims (get-in db2 [kl :items]))
#'boot.user/ims
boot.user=> ims
{"i15059" {:name "ESS1", :done? false}, "i15064" {:name "ESS2", :done? false}, "i15114" {:name "ESS3", :done? false}, "i15121" {:name "ESS3", :done? false}}
boot.user=> (first ims)
["i15059" {:name "ESS1", :done? false}]
boot.user=> (nth ims 1)

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type: PersistentArrayMap
boot.user=>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly what you're looking for, but did you try `(nth (seq ims) 1)`?

Comment: You can't rely on the order of a standard map. You'd typically either access a nested map using a function like `get-in` (which would require keyword/string keys, not positions), or turn the sub-maps into a sequence and iterate over them.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see. So the `first` function should not work too. Is the `first` function a fake for the standard map?

Comment: @trzczy The ordering of a Map depends on the length of the map, and the hash of the keys of the entries (iirc). It's a definite ordering, but not a easily predictable one. I'm pretty sure `first` just ends up calling `seq` on the map, and that defines the ordering, but this behavior is necessary for maps to be compatible with the relevant library functions (like `map` and `reduce`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map is unordered (unless you explicitly created a `sorted-map`).  When you get the map entries (such as a `for` loop or `first`), Clojure silently calls `seq` on the map to get a "list-like" sequence of `MapEntry` items:

```
(def mappy {:c 3 :d 4 :a 1 :b 2 })

mappy          => {:c 3, :d 4, :a 1, :b 2}
(seq mappy)    => ([:c 3] [:d 4] [:a 1] [:b 2])
(vec mappy)    => [[:c 3] [:d 4] [:a 1] [:b 2]]
(first mappy)  => [:c 3]
```

Note that a `seq` prints like a list, but isn't.  A MapEntry prints like a vector, but isn't.

```
(seq mappy)    => <#clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap$Seq ([:c 3] [:d 4] [:a 1] [:b 2])>

(first mappy)  => <#clojure.lang.MapEntry [:c 3]>
```

Once you have some sequential object (vector, list, or seq), you can use `nth` to get the items one at a time:

```
(let [mapseq (seq mappy)
      mapvec (vec mappy) ]

  (nth mapseq 3) => [:b 2]
  (nth mapvec 3) => [:b 2]
```

However, note that the returned item is still a `MapEntry`, not a 2-vector.

```
  (nth mapseq 3) => <#clojure.lang.MapEntry [:b 2]>
  (nth mapvec 3) => <#clojure.lang.MapEntry [:b 2]>
```

You can get the key and value from the MapEntry using `key` and `val` functions:

```
(key (nth mapseq 3)) => :b
(val (nth mapvec 3)) => 2
```

---

P.S. You can print a value & its type as above [using the `spyxx` function](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging).